# Can't seem to fetch data from SeatGeek API

Tags: javascript, api, express

So I'm trying to retrieve data when a user inputs a performer's name with the [SeatGeek](http://platform.seatgeek.com/) API. At the moment, I'm simply typing in the query string in my URL to make sure my Key is working. So this:

```
https://api.seatgeek.com/2/events?performers.slug=new-york-mets&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID
```

Works, and I can get a JSON with information about New York Mets events.

Example:

```
  "meta": {
    "total": 192,
    "per_page": 10,
    "page": 1,
    "took": 2,
    "geolocation": null
  },
  "events": [ARRAY OF EVENTS]
```

Server side and fetching data:

Inside my form I'm making a POST request to `/events`:

```
app.post('/events', function(req, res) {
  let band = req.body.bandName;
  band = band.split(' ').join('-')

  fetch(`https://api.seatgeek.com/2/events?performers.slug=${band}&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID`)
    .then(function(data){
      res.json(data);
    }).catch(function(error){
      console.log(error);
    });
});
```

When I hit the POST request, I get different data. I'm not even entirely sure what this is:

```
{
  "url": "https://api.seatgeek.com/2/events?performers.slug=new-york-mets&client_id=OTk1Mzg2MXwxNTEzMTkwMDUyLjI3",
  "status": 200,
  "statusText": "OK",
  "headers": {
...
 "body": {
"_readableState": {
  "objectMode": false,
  "highWaterMark": 16384,
  "buffer": {
    "head": null,
    "tail": null,
    "length": 0
  }, etc...
```

Am I doing the fetch request wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object you get back from `fetch` in the `then`.

The idea is that `Response` is a *stream* of data, and to actually access the data you get back from an API, you need to read the `Response` stream to completion.

To access the actual fetched JSON, you'll need to access [`Body.json`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json), a method available to responses because they implement the `Body` interface:

```
fetch(`https://api.seatgeek.com/2/events?performers.slug=${band}&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID`)
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  }).then(function(json) {
    res.json(json);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Notice the new `then`. `response.json()` reads the `Response` stream to completion and actually returns a promise that resolves with the JSON when the stream is exhausted. The first `then` waits for the JSON, and after, sends the fetched JSON from SeatGeek to your own API's user in the second `then`.

Comment: Thaaaank you, that was confusing. I simply assumed fetch would return a promise.

Comment: @user7496931 it does, but the promise resolves *to a Response object* not the actual data, which is what you see. That's because you need to signify what type (JSON, plain text, Blob, etc) you want that data in.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks again.